# Нужна помощь по взаимодействию табличных частей документа 1С 8.3

Tags: 1с

Уважаемые Программисты, помогите советом или рецептом. Дано: форма документа с двумя табличными частями (ТЧ). Первая ТЧ - это Услуги, вторая ТЧ - Исполнители. Нужно сделать так, чтобы после добавления одной или нескольких услуг, можно было для каждой из них указать одного или нескольких исполнителей. При этом, чтобы данные эти сохранялись в этом документе без его проведения, а при переключении строк в ТЧ Услуги, можно было увидеть назначенных исполнителей в ТЧ Исполнители. Большое спасибо, всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: Табличные части - в самом документе или просто на форме таблицы значений?!